# INTERACTIVE user permissions

Tags: c#, installshield

I'm using Install Shield Limited Edition and the installer will add a new user called INTERACTIVE to the folder location that only has read permissions.

Is there a way to remove this new user or modify it so it has full permissions?

Answer (score 0):

[Directory.SetAccessControl](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directory.setaccesscontrol%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) applies access control list (ACL) entries described by a DirectorySecurity object to the specified directory.

```
public static void AddDirectorySecurity(string FileName, string Account, FileSystemRights Rights, AccessControlType ControlType)
    {
        // Create a new DirectoryInfo object.
        DirectoryInfo dInfo = new DirectoryInfo(FileName);

        // Get a DirectorySecurity object that represents the  
        // current security settings.
        DirectorySecurity dSecurity = dInfo.GetAccessControl();

        // Add the FileSystemAccessRule to the security settings. 
        dSecurity.AddAccessRule(new FileSystemAccessRule(Account,
                                                        Rights,
                                                        ControlType));

        // Set the new access settings.
        dInfo.SetAccessControl(dSecurity);

    }
```